# Rails: Legacy DB with non-numeric ID fields: No Route Matches 'Show'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scaffolding

I have a legacy DB (Pervasive).
At set intervals I'm doing a clean export/import into MySQL tables.
A created views that mask the ugliness, including renaming the bizarrely named, non-numeric PK fields to 'ID'.

I created a Rails 3 application, and generated scaffolding for the Customer model.
From the Rails console I can pull back data, so the data layer is working.

When I navigate to http://0.0.0.0:3000/customers, I get the following error:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"customers", :id=>#<Customer id: "FGY-164", name:"Ferrari Corp"....`

I'm completely new to Rails, so I'm probably doing something weird.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check out your routes.rb and check you have: -

get "customer/pagename"

Also have a look in the app/views/customer folder and see if it has any pages in there.

Comment: The only thing in routes.rb is `resources :customers`.  The `app/views/customer` folder has all the relevant, generated erb files.